# Copy LocalDB in Winform gives me a 'File being used by another process'

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, localdb

I'm developing a Windows Forms App with VS2012. The data is stored in a SQL Server LocalDB. I'm also using EF6.

At some point I want to zip and send the .mdf file to a server for backup.

The problem is I'm getting the following error 'The process cannot access the file '[filepath]' because it is being used by another process'.

Now I understand that it's my app that is locking the file, but is there any way to unlock it? Or maybe kill the sqlserver client engine?

I'm even considering backing up the localDB File. Is this possible in a winform app?

Comment: This might not be possible in your situation, but it sounds like something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is more in line with your needs if you're sending around database files from individual local application instances.

Comment: Did you try to create a normal backup using the T-SQL BACKUP command?

Comment: As Steve suggested, if you want to make a backup, it's probably best to actually use the build in Sql Server commands for creating a backup, then copying the mdf/ldf files (which can actually cause the database to be corrupt while in use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it now, but I suggest to execute a standard [T-SQL BACKUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) command, then take the BAK file, zip it and store/send it.

```
string backupDB = @"FullPathToYourBackupFile.bak";
string databaseName = "YourDBName"; // This is not the MDF file, but the logical database name
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var cmd = string.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK='{1}' WITH FORMAT;",
                            databaseName, backupDB);
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd, null);
}
```

Comment: This is a much more proper way to accomplish a backup than copying a .mdf.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to you all I got this working.

I used Steve's answer but with some modifications.

```
        string backupDB = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Constants.Paths.CompressedProjects, Constants.DataBase.FileNameBackup);
        string databaseName = Constants.DataBase.LogicalName; // This is not the MDF file, but the logical database name

        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            string[] parms = new string[2];
            parms[0] = databaseName;
            parms[1] = backupDB;

            var cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE " + databaseName + " TO DISK='" + backupDB + "' WITH FORMAT;";
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, cmd, parms);
        }
```

params in ExecuteSqlCommand cannot be null and I had to add a TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction because I was getting this error

> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction

Uploading the LocalDB is now working.

Thank you so much for your help.

Hugo Maurício

Comment: You are passing parameters, but not using them. You could change your command to be 'BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK={1} WITH FORMAT;' and then pass in the databaseName and backupDB as the params.

Comment: @quip The EF parameter syntax should be `BACKUP DATABASE @p0 TO DISK=@p1 WITH FORMAT`, but otherwise agreed.

Answer (score 1):

just found out a new solution

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
```

I tested it and it works

Hugo